# Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.8.21

Tags: android

I just updated all my dependencies, gradle, etc. and still getting:

Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.8.21
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

This is a legacy code so I don't know why this is needed, somebody any idea if this was maybe needed in the past and not anymore, and why the issue could be? I'm working with only latest versions of all.

Comment: That library is available on `mavenCentral`:  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.8.21 Make sure this repository is added to the list of repositories in Gradle.